# how to replace & to and in php

Tags: php

I want to replace special characters like &,%,$ to string.

I have a string s1= Trinidad & Tobago, i want to replace '&' to 'and' 
eg: s1 = Trinidad & Tobago should get replaced to s1= Trinidad and Tobago.

Comment: see [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace)

Comment: What's special about `&`, % and $? What efforts have you shown so far?

Comment: str_replace('&', 'and', $s1);

Comment: What hinders you just doing it? What is your concrete issue? Have you ever heard that there are string functions?

Comment: Thanks, that was easy one. i messed it up sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo str_replace( "&", "and", 'Trinidad & Tobago');
//"Triniad and Tobago"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace):

```
$s1 = str_replace('&', 'and', $s1);
```

If you need to replace multiple characters, str_replace accepts an array as input (both for search and replace):

```
$s1 = str_replace(array('&', '%', '$'), array('and', 'percent', 'dollar'), $s1);
```